# Using get_dummies(), but it's not working on array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, encoding

I am trying the encode a column in a dataset using Pandas get_dummies, but it returns 0 as it is not filtering each keyword in the array in the column.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Load Movies Metadata
metadata = pd.read_csv('moviesNew1.csv', low_memory=False)
print(metadata.info())
cat_columns = ['genres']

df_processed = pd.get_dummies(metadata, 
    prefix_sep="__",columns=cat_columns)

print(df_processed.head(10))
```

It should add 1 to types of movies for correct movie and 0 for not matching.

Answer (score 1):

## TWO STEP SOLUTION:

You should put in your column to be transformed into the data argument. My data:

```
   score    genres
0      1    crime
1      2  romance
2      1   horror
3      4    crime
```

```
df_processed = pd.get_dummies(metadata['genres'])

Result:

   crime  horror  romance
0      1       0        0
1      0       0        1
2      0       1        0
3      1       0        0
```

Now we got our dummies. But to get them back into the original dataframe with the other features, I do:

```
df_concat = pd.concat([df_processed, metadata], axis=1)

Result:

   score    genre  crime  horror  romance
0      1    crimi      1       0        0
1      2  romance      0       0        1
2      1   horror      0       1        0
3      4    crimi      1       0        0
```

## ONE STEP SOLUTION:

The following solution would do the above steps in one go. So if you're not interested in the dummy variables in a seperate DF the do this:

```
df_processed = pd.get_dummies(metadata, columns=['genre'])
```

Comment: Thank you my friend. May the force be with you.